# How to transform HTML string using XSLT in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xslt, saxon-js

I have a string from in a Node.js app that I need to transform using XSLT on the server side. The main "transformations" I need to do are removing specific HTML tags and I can't use regex due to security/performance issues. I will also be using the result of the transformation to then make POST requests to an API.

A simple example may look something like:

```
"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed suscipit felis. Aliquam porttitor gravida velit, et facilisis est viverra a. Suspendisse potenti.</p>\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed suscipit felis. Suspendisse potenti.</p>"
```

And I need to transform it to the following (basically just remove `<p>` tags in this case):

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed suscipit felis. Aliquam porttitor gravida velit, et facilisis est viverra a. Suspendisse potenti.\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed suscipit felis. Suspendisse potenti."
```

Here are the main questions I have:

- Can I use saxon-js to make these changes? If so, I am struggling to figure out how based on their docs.
- Is there another way to implement XSLT on a node app?

Comment: I'm interested to know where you got stuck following the documentation. Was it installing/configuring the product? Was it writing Javascript code to invoke the transformation? Was it writing the XSLT code? Or was it just understanding how everything should fit together?

Comment: hey @MichaelKay - thanks for reaching out. I'd like to preface my response that I've only been coding for about a year now and I just started learning about XSLT a few days ago so the saxon-js package may be a bit advanced for me. But to answer your question, the part that I got stuck on was trying to figure out how to set up the XSL and JSON files. I missed in the docs about using the `xslt3` command to generate the `books.sef.json` file. So when I was reading through the examples that are provided, I was confused. Looking back, I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I took the bait, here is how you can do that with SaxonJS:

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js")

var input = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed suscipit felis. Aliquam porttitor gravida velit, et facilisis est viverra a. Suspendisse potenti.</p>\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed suscipit felis. Suspendisse potenti.</p>";

const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

var result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(
  map {
    'source-node' : parse-xml-fragment($xml),
    'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
    'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
    }
)?output`,
[],
{ params : {
    xml : input,
    xslt : xslt
  }
});
   
 console.log(result);
```

Using output method text will remove all elements, if you don't want that use the default and add `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` and add templates for those elements you want to preserve e.g. `<xsl:template match="h1"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` or approach it the other way around and use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` and block what you don't want with matching templates doing e.g. `<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`.

And in the end, once your stylesheet works and is finished, you should "compile" it with e.g. `xslt3 -nogo -xsl:sheet.xsl -export:sheet.sef.json` to SEF/JSON and then use the direct transformation API from JavaScript e.g. `SaxonJS.transform`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MartinHonnen. 

I would like to scale my Node app to allow other users to use it so if I compiled a stylesheet, would they have to do the same thing within their local environment? i.e. is the connection between a stylesheet and the JS file (Saxon functions) specific to the environment they are on? I see there's a BaseUri field in the sef.json file which points to the specific file.

Comment: @alex-deg, the `xslt3` tool has a `-relocate` option you can set to `1` or `yes` or `on` to "Produce relocatable packages", as far as I am aware there is no need for other to recompile a code, you can use/distribute an SEF/JSON file as part of your app.